# youtube-dl problem

Tags: youtube-dl

my ubuntu is showing me this error:

```
abhishek@abhishek-ThinkPad-R61:~$ youtube-dl -f worst http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGhx-u-c5Cg
[youtube] Setting language
WARNING: unable to set language: nonnumeric port: 'port_no'
[youtube] QGhx-u-c5Cg: Downloading video webpage
ERROR: unable to download video webpage: nonnumeric port: 'port_no'
abhishek@abhishek-ThinkPad-R61:~$
```

Comment: you could update the utility with `sudo youtube-dl -U` and then check if that fixed the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding as a service in Konqueror browser the youtube-dl addon. You can find it in Konqueror - Settings - Configure Konqueror - Services, and once you get here press the Download New Services button, and look for youtube-dl or video-dl package and install it.

Comment: How does this answer the question? How do you know OP is using Kubuntu or KDE or Konqueror?

Comment: I use Konqueror in Xubuntu right now, no big deal, and also installed it in Lubuntu in the past. It is true that Konqueror browser comes with a bunch of other packages but it works fine, and it is a fast and decent browser for any Ubuntu based distro.